# Chimney without a cover cap or a flue lining

Tags: chimney

I have a house that was built in 1969. In addition to this, a former owner was an avid DIY-er (based on neighbor anecdotes).

Late last year i was on the roof and looked down the chimney. Apparently they do not have a flue liner nor a chimney cap! I plan to get a chimney inspector to take a look (when it's dry and sunny). But for now, I just have to try to ignore the chimney.

Any warning signs I can be looking out for?

Comment: No flue liiner, like clay flue or stainless steel flue liner?

Comment: Warning signs for what? If you're not using the chimney, what misfortune are you seeking to avoid?